# Finding a regex patterned text inside a python variable

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
    # Ex1
    # Number of datasets currently listed on data.gov
    # http://catalog.data.gov/dataset


    import requests
    import re

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    page = requests.get(
        "http://catalog.data.gov/dataset")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    value = soup.find_all(class_='new-results')

    results = re.search([0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9], value


    print(value)
```

The code is above .. I want to find a text in the form on regex =  [0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]

inside the text inside the variable 'value'

How can i do this ?

Based on ShellayLee's suggestion i changed it to

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get(
    "http://catalog.data.gov/dataset")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

value = soup.find_all(class_='new-results')

my_match = re.search(r'\d\d\d,\d\d\d', value)


print(my_match)
```

STILL GETTING ERROR

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex1.py", line 19, in 
    my_match = re.search(r'\d\d\d,\d\d\d', value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

You need some basics of regex in Python. A regex in Python is represented in as a string, and `re` module provides functions like `match`, `search`, `findall` which can take a string as an argument and treat it as a pattern.

In your case, the pattern `[0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]` can be represented as:

```
my_pattern = r'\d\d\d,\d\d\d'
```

then used like

```
my_match = re.search(my_pattern, value_text)
```

where `\d` means a digit symbol (same as `[0-9]`). The `r` leading the string means the backslaches in the string are not treated as escaper.

The search function returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

---

I suggest you walk through some tutorials first to get rid of further confusions. The official HOWTO is already well written:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html

Comment: @BinuAlexander If you find the answer helpful please give me an upvote :)